# Why is the direction of the electric field that will balance the weight of an electron downward, and a proton upward?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrons, electric-fields, protons

Here is the full question from problem,

What are the magnitude and direction of the electric field that will balance the weight of the following?

An electron

A proton

For an electron/proton we use the equation $qE = mg$. Therefore the answer for magnitude would just to multiply the mass of an electron/proton by 9.8. But how come the direction for electron is upward, and proton is downward?

Answer (score 2):

Your question ask for the electric field, that in your equation is `E`. Also, the electric force must be the opposite of gravity so that both will cancel out, you are missing the minus sign:

$$ E = - { mg \over q } $$

Being $q = -1$ for the electron and $q = +1$ for the proton.

You can consider that $g$ is a vector pointing downwards, so $E$ for the electron will point downwards and for the proton it will point upwards.

Answer (score 0):

It should help you to consider the direction of the electric field generated by charges and what forces would act on a proton or electron positioned there.

[image]

<sub>Source: [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:VFPt_charges_plus_minus_thumb.svg)</sub>